# Reaper and iZotope RX --> workflow issue

Tags: reaper, izotope, workflow

Hi there,

I use a combination of Reaper and Izotope RX to clean some audio tracks of a bunch of video clips. I need both the the spectral tools of izotope of and the multitrack sequencing and the video decoding of reaper to make a achieve my work.

However I can't find an efficient way to work with these 2 tools at the same time. The Spectral Repair vst plug-in is not supported by Reaper, so I configured Izotope RX as the main external editor to always keep a hand on restoration tools from my session. But There are two flaws handling things this way. First.I can't track the Reaper cursor position in the file I open for edition. I have to manually seek in Izotope RX where is the region I want to deal with. Second, I can't have any video feedback when I am working in Izotope RX. Sometimes I prefer to keep working in the RX editor where there is a large amount of audio to fix, but without the video  playback sync to my audio I feel uncomfortable.

How do you guys usually handle this kind of work?

Answer (score 2):

When I need to do spectral repair I separate that section of audio, use my special key-command, it makes a copy of that section as a new file, and opens it in RX standalone.

The trick is to make RX your default external editor. Then in the mouse modifiers section setup 'open item copy in external editor'. I think mine is control+option+command+double-click.

From your description it sounds like you're opening the whole original file rather than just the portion that needs repair.

I don't work with video though so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to bag reaper as it is a good DAW and I use it often, however my main DAW is Sequoia. I use Izotope for mastering, but not the RX package. If you can afford RX, you might find in investigating one of the other DAW packages that it supports the workflow you require.